# Sprite Frames are getting confused

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Just a quick question, when using sprite sheets and plists with coocs2d does the animations call each frame by name or does it run through the rows of the image? I am getting some frame confusions where its displaying a frame from a different sequence, say it shows a jump frame when its running. Any pointers would be helpful!

The problem seems to be when I add multiple actions

```
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];                    //Animation Frames
        for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Standing_%d.png",i]]];
        }

        NSMutableArray *runAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=1; i<=11; i++) {
            [runAnimFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Running_%d.png",i]]];
        }

        NSMutableArray *jumpAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
            [runAnimFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rwby_jump%d.png",i]]];
        }



        CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation
                                 animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];          //Animations
        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                           [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];


        CCAnimation *runAnim = [CCAnimation
                                animationWithSpriteFrames:runAnimFrames delay:0.1125f];
        self.runAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                          [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:runAnim]];

        CCAnimation *jumpAnim = [CCAnimation
                                animationWithSpriteFrames:jumpAnimFrames delay:0.1125f];
        self.jumpAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                          [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:jumpAnim]];
```

Comment: hmmm ... you are adding your jump frames to the runAnimFrames array instead of the jumpAnimFrames array.

Comment: Thank you! it was giving me so much trouble!